# Validation of relationship cardinality not working as expected

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, relationship-class, arcfm, validation

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.1 with ArcFM extensions, and the ArcGIS validation tool.

I have a feature class (poles) with several subtypes based on construction materials.  It is related to a table via a relationship class that also has several subtypes which indicate different equipment that can be attached to the poles.  To troubleshoot, I have set up every rule in the relationship to the effect

> "a [wooden/concrete/fiberglass] pole must have between 0 and 1
>   [thingies/doohickies/whatzits]".

Validation under this scenario work, but we're deprecating a pole subtype, so I do not want any related records attached to it.  Essentially,

> "a [wooden/fiberglass] pole must have between 0 and 1 
>   thingies/doohickies/whatzits]".
>
> "a [concrete] pole must have between 0 and 0 [thingies/doohickies/whatzits]".
>
> Alternatively, I have tried leaving the checkboxes unchecked for all equipment where related to concrete pole subtype.

Either way, things get squirrely.  When I encounter poles that do not have attachments, they validate successfully.  If I validate a wooden pole with one whatzit attached, it fails with a message

> "The feature pole (subtype: wood) may not be related to
>   material(subtype: whatzit) because there is no relationship rule."

If I validate a wooden pole with two whatzits attached, I get

> "The feature pole (subtype: wood) has 2 related material(subtype: whatzit) features, thus violating the equipment relationship rule that specifies 0-1."

Do I have to define cardinality for all pole sybtypes, even unused ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, there are two things at play here:
1) Features are indeed violating cardinality rules
2) ESRI bug in that the message is not indicating the correct rule being violated